# The etymology of anafunctor?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, math-history

This could very well be me overlooking some very obvious connection, or some obscure prefix in English, but I've scoured all of the original material introducing the concept of [anafunctors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/anafunctor), namely [Makkai (1996)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(95)00029-1), and including the nLab page I linked to, and nowhere in it is the prefix "ana-" explained at all. Did it just... sprout of nowhere, invented out of thin air by the author? Is it short for some other word? This is rather baffling, because there are at least hints to an answer for most other terms in mathematics.

Disclaimer, that this is mostly for my own curiosity. I just saw a lack of answer, or even question, about this, so I had to ask. I appreciate any responses in advance.

Comment: The prefix *an-* usually stands for negation.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA generally, true. But it isn't an-functor, or non-functor, or dis-functor, or co-functor, or other variations of negation that generally make sense. It's making use of either a really obscure, or completely new and unique prefix. Not only that, it comes with a whole zoo of other concepts: anafunctors, ananatural transformations, anamonoidal categories, anabicategories, etc. You could still be correct, and the author could have used 'an-', or extended to 'ana-', to simply mean 'alternative' functor.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%80%CE%BD%CE%AC#Ancient_Greek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the relevant part in the original article introducing the notion of anafunctor, which is linked to in the question. On page 6 of the article (so, p. 114 on the journal), the author notes:

> The use of the prefix "ana" has been suggested by Dusko Pavlovic. He noted the use of "pro-" in category theory (profunctor, proobject), and noted that in biology, the terms "anaphase" and "prophase" are used in the same context.

So, the term originates from biology, in analogy (pun unintended) between the terms "prophase" and "anaphase", and "profunctor" and "anafunctor".

Comment: +1- So, in a nutshell: back functor (ana-) vs forward functor (pro-)...